# Entity Framework Core Log Warnings

Tags: c#, sql, logging, entity-framework-core

How to log warnings in Entity Framework Core in C#, when query cannot be translated to SQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you seeing this issue? Linq To Entities or something else?

Comment: When some query cannot be translate to pure SQL, query will be evaluate in memory. I want to know about it. So I need to log this warnings.